# How to customize DbContext properties names in Entity Framework and stop being overwritted?

Tags: entity-framework

EF auto-generate the DbContext class from my edmx file (database first) and use table names as default names for all this DbContext properties (ex: `public DbSet<Student> student { get; set; }`)

If I make some change in this file (ex: like renaming properties name from student to Students), my changes are lost everytime I save my model because EF regenerate the DbContext class file.

How can I change this default behaviour and be able to make my customization and stop losing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate on what Pawel said.. The EDMX file (the designer) is the source of everything.  Any changes you need to make to the generated items should be done there.  You can add additional methods or properties through partial classes, but you can't change existing ones.. so it must be changed in the source EDMX file.

Just right click on the Table in the designer, and rename it.  This doesn't change the underlying table name (at least in Database First reverse engineering, model first is a different story).

Comment: Ok for the table names but what about the method names in my Entities class that inherit from DbContext? (In MyDataModel.Context.cs)

Comment: @Etienne - What method names?  Poco's are called Poco's for a reason.  They don't have methods.

Comment: The T4 template give me a MyDataModel.Context.tt which contain a MyDataModel.Context.cs. Inside this last one we have the definition of  the public partial class Entities : DbContext that contain the list of all methods (ex: public DbSet<Student> student { get; set; }). Inside my repositories, after having instantiated this Entities  class (ex: private Entities context;) I can access my model using context.student... I would like to access it using context.Students... Sorry for not being able to be clear...

Comment: @Etienne - Those are properties, not methods.  And when you say "Entities" you typically are referring to the Student class, which is an Entity, not the derived context.  In any event We've already told you how to change this.  You change it in the Model designer.

Comment: Ok, I have found it. In the Model designer, when you right click a model and go to properties, you have the Name property but also the "Entity Set Name" property that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it in the Edmx file - you should be able to do that with the EF Designer